# How to present new view in SwiftUI after login

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I need to know who to present a new view using SwiftUI (following MVVM design pattern).

For example, once the user enters the credentials to login, pressing the "login" button should take them to the home page of the app without being able to return to the login page.

I have been looking at the documentation from Apple, as well as other questions in Stackoverflow, but they all seem to be using navigation views (i.e. there is a navigation bar at the top which allows the user to return to the previous view).

Below is the code of how I would have accomplished this using UIKit, as well as an image to visually represent what I want to accomplish.

`let vc = MainMenuController()`

`vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

`self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);`

[Sample image of desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH1gu.png)

Answer (score 1):

this is how i implemented it in my code in `ContentView.swift`:

```
@State var loggedIn: Bool = false

var body: some View {
  VStack {
    if loggedIn {
      ShowSomeTabView()
    } else {
      ShowLoginScreen()
    }
  }.onAppear {
    self.checkAuthorized()
  }
}

private func checkAuthorized() {
  if loggedIn() {
    self.loggedIn = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what are you doing in the functions ShowSomeTabView() and ShowLoginScreen()? I think that might answer my initial question.